# Cisco VPN connection active but not access to server

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, vpn

What a double click on windows does turns out to be a nightmare on ubuntu. I've received a .p12 certificate to connect to the server I'm working at.

What I've done with that file:

- openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out DB.pem -clcerts
- openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out db.key
- Open Network -> Add new VPN (+) -> Select Cisco AnyConnect

  - Details: Make available to other users
  - VPN Protocol: Cisco AnyConnect or openconnect (I need Cisco)
  - Gateway: server address (received from it admin)
  - CA Certificate: cert.pem
  - User Certificate: DB.pem
  - Private Key: db.key
  - Everything else is unchanged

I can then successfully establish the connection.
`nmcli connection show` returns the following information:

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE          
VPN 2               41f0e...............................  vpn       enp7s0          
Wired connection 1  99ce4...............................  ethernet  enp7s0          
br-bca2dbd44efa     b5f2b...............................  bridge    br-bca2dbd44efa 
vpn0                9d5be...............................  tun       vpn0            
docker0             1c8d5...............................  bridge    docker0         
dhzb                b3f4b...............................  vpn       --              
dhzb2               536e0...............................  vpn       --              
HeimWLAN            e12a4...............................  wifi      --              
VPN 1               c78b3...............................  vpn       --
```

The intranet website is not reachable.

```
This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in intranet.abcxxx.de

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

And a ping says 'Name or service not known.'

A remote desktop connection with Remmina is hence also not possible.

I'm thankful for every help and let me know what information are missing to solve the problem.

**Solution**

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome

openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.p12 -out myfile.pem -clcerts

sudo openconnect -c myfile.pem vpn.myserverxyz.de
```